# Preventing firebase Out of memory exception using Realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am trying to get data of a specific user when they log in, currently this is working well using the `.child(userId)` & `.get()` methods for a small amount of data/records. However, I created over 50,000+ test users & it ended up crashing on the android app.

**My simple code for retrieving user data:**

```
realtimeDatabase.getReference("users")
                .child(userId)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DataSnapshot result = task.getResult();
                        if (result != null && result.exists()) {
                            Map<String, Object> mainMap = (Map<String, Object>) result.getValue();
                       //I should equate the result to a POJO instead of a Map, but I'll sort it out later :)

                            UserList userList = new UserList();
                            userList.setPoints((Long) mainMap.get("points"));

                            if (userList != null) {
                                long currentNoOfPoints = userList.getPoints();
                                ...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I've checked out similar posts on SO & the common solution is using `.limitToFirst(...)` & equivalent methods... however in my case, I'm not showing the data on a list but simply want to retrieve the data for the user. In addition, correct me if I'm wrong getting the data using the `.child(...)` method is the same as creating a index since the whole node isn't retrieved.

**The error trace I'm getting is:**

```
E/RunLoop: Firebase Database encountered an OutOfMemoryError. You may need to reduce the amount of data you are syncing to the client (e.g. by using queries or syncing a deeper path). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 524304 byte allocation with 434072 free bytes and 423KB until OOM, target footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592
    at java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:703)
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:628)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
```

How can I solve this issue?

**Edit**

**The exported 'users' node data looks like this**

```
"users": {
"-N8sU8jQ0zE9klo8ukKC": {
  "account_status": "active",
  "displayName": "w9R5uBiYoQ",
  "points": 39188,
  "profilePic": "-"
},
"-N8sU8j__vlLa_UCCgvc": {
  "account_status": "active",
  "displayName": "LqO7LE9P95",
  "points": 35743,
  "profilePic": "-"
},
...
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the data you have under `/users/$uid` (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffele, I've done so & pasted some portion of it, since its a large set of data

Comment: Are you load all data for all 50,000 users when you get this error? Or does it happen when you load a single user, with the code in your question?

Comment: It only happens when I'm loading data for a single user as shown in the posted code, unless it also loads all the other user data

Comment: A single user seems unlikely to use up all memory. Did you enable disk persistence by any chance? And if so, did you set `keepSynced(true)` on one of the higher-level nodes in your database?

Comment: No, I haven't, I'm using all the default settings. To ensure that I'm not doing anything wrong or loading all the data, I'll try to create another firebase test project and see if I end up with the same exception

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a good plan. I just don't see how that small JSON snippet could be requiring that much memory. I hope the repro gives a hint, or that somebody else spots something I may be overlooking.

Comment: I cannot see either how a single user can use up all memory. Are you reading data from other parts of your code?

Comment: I did & realized I was pulling all the users in a different activity, since the crash was only occurring in the MainActivity